# p-autoComplete requires two clicks to show selected value

Tags: angular, primeng

**Current behavior**

When an option is selected, the selected value is not shown, although the value binds properly. In order to display the option properly, have to click on the same option once more.

This issue comes when the `p-autoComplete` element is created dynamically using a `*ngFor`. Am I doing anything wrong here? Is there another/correct way to achieve the same thing I am doing here? (dynamic element generation) Or is it a bug?

Check following stackblitz to replicate the issue : https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-zbphun

**Expected behavior**

When an option is selected, the current selection should be displayed

**Environment**
* **Angular version:** 7.2.0

- **PrimeNG version:** 7.0.5
- **Browser:** Chrome 72
- **Language:** TypeScript 3.2
- **Node:** v10.15.0

Comment: Its working in stackblitz. Could you please check. I must be missing something

Comment: @HardikPatel I think you're answer is correct. Why did you remove it? I did some changes to the onSelect() method as well. Now the values bind properly. Earlier the values weren't getting bound properly after your change

Comment: reverted back thanks k9yosh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `[(ngModel)]="commonInfoValueList[i].value"` with `[(ngModel)]="common.value"`